# What should be the expected behavior when I call MPI_IRecv/MPI_Recv when there're no messages

Tags: mpi

I'm new to MPI so bear with me.
I could find any documents on what the expected behavior is in this case.

Let's say I have proc #1 calling `MPI_IRecv` from `ANY_SOURCE` but no one has ever sent anything to proc #1, would I receive an empty buffer or would I get an error?

Answer (score 2):

Since `MPI_IRecv` is the asynchronous version, basically nothing will happen at first.

If you e.g. `MPI_Wait` on the resulting request the same thing will happen as if you called `MPI_Recv` directly: Your program will (usually) block until a fitting message arrives.

If you do not ever send that message, your program simply starves.

Note: The "usually" refers to all the possible cases in which an error is created due to some other related or unrelated issue.